# In XSLT, how can a textfield be padded with spaces?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, padding, spacing

I have a table with three fields, like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="innerBodyColor">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:303px"><label class="Label" for="First">First:</label></th>
        <th style="width:181px"><label class="Label" for="Second">Second:</label></th>
        <th style="width:117px"><label class="Label" for="Third">Third:</label></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-right: 5 px">
                <xsl:call-template name="text">
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'First'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="fontSize" select="'Large'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="editType" select="'AlphanumericSC'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="maxLength" select="'16'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="width" select="'303'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="onValueChange">handleValueChange(); setHidden(); padSpaces(); </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-right: 5 px">
                <xsl:call-template name="text">
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Second'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="fontSize" select="'Large'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="editType" select="'AlphanumericSC'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="maxLength" select="'12'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="width" select="'181'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="onValueChange">padSpaces(); </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
            <td style="">
                <xsl:call-template name="text">
                    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Third'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="fontSize" select="'Large'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="editType" select="'AlphanumericSC'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="maxLength" select="'10'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="width" select="'117'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="onValueChange">padSpaces(); </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I'm using the function padSpaces() to attempt to pad each field with a given number of spaces.

That function looks like this:

```
function padSpaces()
{
    var first = getValueById('First').replace(/\s/g, '');
    var second = getValueById('Second');
    var third = getValueById('Third');

    while (first.length < 16)
    {
        first += " ";
    }
    setValueById('First', first)
}
```

And this works, somewhat.  It does, in fact, pad the first field to be 16 characters, but it makes it difficult to work with the field, because it adds the necessary whitespace (to get to its maximum length of 16) every time the field is modified.  This is probably because the code is being executed "onValueChange" rather than when the user finishes entering data into the field.

Is there either:

1) some other way of padding the field with spaces without calling a function; or

2) some other way of having the function execute, instead of executing every time the value of the field changes?

Comment: I can't see how this is anything to do with XSLT, it looks more like it's your javascript that's the issue. 2nd point, why do you need to pad it? If it's for layout, HTML/CSS has better ways of doing it. If it's because a later part of the process needs it padded, pad it before it's processed.

Comment: This is not an [xslt] question: XSLT is used just to create some HTML + javascript; I would suggest editing the question to show the resulting HTML `input` element instead of the XSLT template, and swap the [xslt] tag for [javascript].